# PHPHtmlParser - $dom->find() only returning first result

Tags: php, html-parsing, simpledom

I am using the [php-html-parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser) package (based [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)) loaded in via Composer and parsing an HTML string, however when using the $dom->find() to loop through all of the elements I am searching for, it is only detecting the first element (out of 29).

```
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$dom = new PHPHtmlParser\Dom;
$dom->load($result); // $result is the output of a cURL request
$classes = $dom->find('li[class=SPECIALCLASS]');
echo count($classes);
foreach($classes as $class){
   echo $class->text;
}
```

Output: 1

Sample HTML:

```
<li class="SPECIALCLASS "></li>
<li class="SPECIALCLASS SOMEOTHERCLASS "></li>
```

EDIT: Dropping the class selector completely results in 5/29 li tags being returned, so I have a feeling there is something bigger at play here.

Comment: What will happen if you try: foreach($dom->find('li[class=SPECIALCLASS]') as $element) { }

Comment: I just installed php-html-parser and tested your script with the sample input and it returns 2 as expected. So maybe the problem is with the sample HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$dom->find('li[contains(@class, "SPECIALCLASS")]');
```

instead of:

```
$dom->find('li[class=SPECIALCLASS]');
```

Comment: This appears to have significantly helped, but I'm now getting 7 results (out of 29) and when I try to loop through them to see what the results are, my find()->text or find()->innerHTML isn't working all of a sudden

Comment: Post the code so we can see what can be the issue. @laiello

Answer (score 0):

none of above solution works for me. I just do a hack

```
while($dom->find("li.SPECIALCLASS", 0)) {
    $class = $dom->find("li.SPECIALCLASS", 0);
    echo $class->text;
    $class->delete();
    unset($class);
}
```

as   PHPHtmlParser\Dom    read only single line in both cases `find("li.class")` and `find("li.class", 0)`. 
so I read first element get data and delete it. in next iteration I will get next class using this logic I loop through all classes